# One corner of the block beveled with box shadow

Tags: css

The designer drew here such a block, which in the future will need to be done adaptively. I came up against how to implement a similar beveled corner with a shadow so that it works in ie11 + and modern versions of the browser. I would be grateful for any hint.

[image]

The question is in the lower right corner, the upper right without problems can be done by superimposing an opaque image, and with the shadow on the bottom right it will be too difficult to please in all browsers.

Comment: Use simple image, it's too complicated for CSS cross-browser

Comment: You can an image for the upper left, and a linear gradient for the bottom right.

Comment: @Justinas Also inclined to the picture. But maybe there is a magic solution that I don’t know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to see what you've tried or the structure of your code. But here's a solution for all modern browsers EXCEPT IE 11. You'll need to do some feature testing to develope a solution for IE specifically.

This uses `CSS Clip-path` and `CSS filter` to produce the effect.

**Important:** 
Clip-path works like `CSS Overflow:hidden` so you can't use a `box-shadow`. Instead you need to add a wrapper and apply the filter to that.

```css
body {
 margin: 100px;
 background-color: #eee
}

.clipped {
 width: 300px;
 clip-path: polygon(
  50px 0, /* top left */
  100% 0, /* top right */
  100% 0, /* right top */
  100% calc(100% - 15px), /* right bottom */
  calc(100% - 15px) 100%, /* bottom right */
  0 100%, /* bottom left */
  0 100%, /* left bottom */
  0 50px); /* left top */
}

.image {
 height: 150px;
 background: transparent url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573645705379-08743e0edf95?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80') top left no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
.content {
 padding: 20px 30px;
 background: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
 filter: drop-shadow(1px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover {
    /* hover to show the shadow is dynamic */
 filter: drop-shadow(-5px -5px 5px #76FF03)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="clipped">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
   Some text to show below images
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For IE support you'll need to use a polyfill like this [one](https://github.com/AlfonsoFilho/ClipPath).

Answer (score -3):

use ::before for top-left and ::after for bottom-right.